# Best way to authenticate/authorize users of a HANA application with LDAP (on-premise, not HCP)

Tags: authentication, ldap, authorization, hana, hana-xs

Running HANA on-premise I want to authenticate users in my xs-application against our existing LDAP-Server.

Furthermore I need to read user-related information from LDAP (like the users group) and provide this information inside of my xs-application.

What is the best way to do/configure this in HANA?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup SAP HANA as Service Provider (SP) and configure XS applications to use SAML, an ADFS can act as SAML Identity Provider (IDP) givin you the information you need. 
There is a good article published here how to setup HANA (google for "sap hana saml"): http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2015/03/14/use-saml-to-enable-sso-for-your-xs-app-on-sap-hana-sps-09-rev-92-or-later

Comment: Also, please note that if your LDAP server is not Active Directory, you would need ADFS 2016 to authenticate users in LDAP directories.